# Table index exception in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a table called `Announcement` and it has unique index on columns `Title` and `Code`.

I am using Entity Framework 6.0.26 for CRUD operations, but I have an issue in inserting/updating data into the mentioned columns.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.InnerException!.Message.Contains("unique index"))
    {
        if (ex.InnerException.Message.Contains("IX_Announcement_Code"))
        {
            throw new Exception("this code is already used");
        }

        if (ex.InnerException.Message.Contains("IX_Announcement_Title"))
        {
            throw new Exception("this title is already used");
        }
    }

    throw new Exception();
}
```

I am using this code to figure out what threw the exception - because of index or not, but I know it is a bad practice to do this.

Is there any exception related to table index?

I know that I can create my custom method for validating (e.g. `Task<bool> TitleAlreadyExists(string title)`) but this is not what I am looking for.

I am looking for a better solution for handling database table index exception.

Comment: Are you referring to violation of a unique constraint error? What is the exception type that is returned in that case? Probably just a SqlException isn't it?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you are handling all exceptions rather than just SqlExceptions, what bad practices are you referring to?

Comment: @DaleK i get **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException** and its inner exception is SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'emp.Announcement' with unique index 'IX_Announcement_Code'. The duplicate key value is (1000).
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: There you go then, you answered you own question, catch that exception and do what you are currently doing inside it. Whats the bad practice you refer to?

Comment: @DaleK throwing `Exception`s instead of more specific exception types for one and throwing exceptions to begin with secondly?

Comment: @AryanRiyahi is your goal to get better exceptions or to get rid of them alltogether?

Comment: Nothing wrong with throwing exceptions... depends why of course... but you are right, you should use a better exception or create your own. Depends how you are handling them, cos if you are throwing them I assume you then use them somewhere?

Comment: @DaleK yes that part is pretty opinionated, whether you consider this use of exceptions an actual *mis*use. But you _could_.

Comment: @AryanRiyahi also note that you can put conditions on the catch additionally `catch( XyzException x ) when ...` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements#a-when-exception-filter

Comment: How about not inserting duplicates in the first place

Comment: @siggemannen love your work... always cut straight through the bullshit to the core of the issue :)

Comment: Anyway I've removed the SQL Server tag, its C# experts you need, not SQL Server experts.

Comment: @fildor all of my entities have title and code, and i am repeating this catch block in all insert/update method in all entities, i am looking for a better solution to catch this exception

Comment: @siggemannen as i mentioned in the question i am unable to create a method to check if **Code** or **Title** already exists

Comment: If you're not able to create such a method then how do you make the distinction between inserts and updates? That said, even if you'd have such a method there will always be some latency between the check and the actual insert/update so IMO handling these exceptions is justified. However, it's largely opinion-based how to do that.

Comment: @GertArnold _"However, it's largely opinion-based how to do that."_ - while I agree with that, there are still points that can objectively be improved, once one of the opinions has been picked. Right?

Comment: @Fildor Sure, as usual, but that still makes it opinion-based.

Answer (score 3):

**Considering your specific request** to *"[i am looking for] a better solution to catch this exception"*:

Catch the most specific Exception-Type reasonable:

```
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
```

Any *other* Exception is unexpected and potentially cannot be handled here. So let those "bubble up".

Perform reasonable sanity checks (maybe using [exception filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements#a-when-exception-filter) - but you can nest this, of course)

```
catch (DbUpdateException ex) when ( ex.InnerException is null )
{
    // throw an application-specific Exception type
    throw new ApplicationUpdateFailedException(ex.Entries);
}
```

Go on to detect your special cases

```
catch (DbUpdateException ex) when ( ex.InnerException is null )
{
    // throw an application-specific Exception type
    throw new ApplicationUpdateFailedException(ex.Entries);
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex) when ( ex.InnerException is not null && 
                                    ex.InnerException.Message.Contains("IX_Announcement_Code"))
{
    // throw an application-specific Exception type
    throw new ApplicationUpdateFailedDuplicateCodeException(ex.Entries);
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex) when ( ex.InnerException is not null && 
                                    ex.InnerException.Message.Contains("IX_Announcement_Title") )
{
    // throw an application-specific Exception type
    throw new ApplicationUpdateFailedDuplicateTitleException(ex.Entries);
}
```

To make this even more readable, you may want to introduce some extension method like

```
internal static class DbUpdateExceptionExtensions
{
    internal static bool IsConflictForIndex(this DbUpdateException ex, string indexName) => 
       ex.InnerException is not null && 
       ex.InnerException.Message.Contains(indexName);
}
```

and then

```
catch (DbUpdateException ex) when ( ex.InnerException is null )
{
    // throw an application-specific Exception type
    throw new ApplicationUpdateFailedException(ex.Entries);
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex) when ( ex.IsConflictForIndex("IX_Announcement_Code"))
{
    // throw an application-specific Exception type
    throw new ApplicationUpdateFailedDuplicateCodeException(ex.Entries);
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex) when ( ex.IsConflictForIndex("IX_Announcement_Title") )
{
    // throw an application-specific Exception type
    throw new ApplicationUpdateFailedDuplicateTitleException(ex.Entries);
}
```

All of this presupposes you have application-specific Exception-types, that may also form an inheritance tree, so you can later decide if you want to catch each individually or as a group of errors.

---

On a separate note:

It's **not a good idea** to do

```
catch(Exception ex) // too broad anyway , ... but
{
    if( yadda yadda )
    {
        // ...
        throw new Exception("Message");
    }
    throw new Exception(); // Stacktrace reset, no message, ... == "Something went wrong" == useless
}
```

You are losing valuable information here. If you have to do something like that in the first place, you might want to consider doing something like:

```
catch(Exception ex) // too broad anyway , ... but
{
    if( yadda yadda )
    {
        // ...
        throw SomethingElseException(ex); // Keep as inner exception
    }
    throw; // rethrow original without reset
}
```

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements#the-throw-statement (Do note the "Note" Box!)

For general best practices see: [Best practices for exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions)

Btw when it comes to **logging exceptions**, Stephen Cleary has us covered: [A New Pattern for Exception Logging](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/06/a-new-pattern-for-exception-logging.html)